# How can I get the names of (particular kinds of) fields in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to get the names of some fields. In particular, I have something like

```
trait Special[T] {
    // do something here
}

class MyClass {
  object x extends Special[Int]
  object y extends Special[String]
  // other fields may be intermixed
  // or I could extend a trait that 
  // has its own fields
}
```

How can I get a list of the fields that extend Special in MyClass? I've tried

```
classOf[MyClass].getDeclaredFields.toList.filter(_.getType.isInstanceOf[Special])
```

and several similar kinds of things, but the parameters keep screwing me up.

I think I'm having a `Class<?>` vs. `Type` issue, but I tried a few experiments with `getInterfaces()` and `getGenericType()` and didn't get any farther.

Please help! :-)
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
classOf[MyClass].getDeclaredFields.filter(_.getType.getInterfaces.contains(classOf[Special[_]]))
```

Comment: That (mostly) did it. You have to add a .toList after getInterfaces.